# Power series centered at c instead of 0, why using a transformation preserves the property

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis

$$\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_{k}x^{k}\qquad \text{ vs  }\qquad\displaystyle g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_{k}(x-a)^{k}$$

My textbook states that if we can make clear of power series $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_{k}x^{k}$ centered at $0$, then by a simple transformation $t=x-a$, then we know the property of $g(x)$. (Such as holomorphic, the radius, the derivative of the power series can be calculated by differentiating by terms and so on). It really confuses me. I think the author tries to composite two functions, but do not know in what way we composite and why it holds since we are working with infinite terms.

Comment: $g(x)=f(x-a){}$